# In-line bootstrap 3 buttons inside dropdown without changing css

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Hello all the community I've searched a lot trough it so many times this is my first time posting ^^ well my question is:
How I put two buttons in the same line using bootstrap 3 with only changing the HTML?

```
<div class="container">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right" >            


         <li class="dropdown">

         <a class="dropdown-toggle " href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Login
            </a>  

          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <form class="navbar-form" role="form">

           <p> 
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="E-mail" />
           </p>


            <p> 
             <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Contrasenya" />
            </p>


             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sing in</button>
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Log in</button>






            </form>
           </div>

          </li>

        </ul>
      </div>
```

[What I have](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwOBDBZckmYweENsNWFGSkx2ekk/edit?usp=sharing)

[What I want](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwOBDBZckmYwN1YweGVCRXZwTUk/edit?usp=sharing)

PD:sorry about my English
PD2:sorry if its to much a stupid question but I've been trying 2 hours and I can't find a solution :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's no way to get what you want without modify CSS. I've tried some things with `.form-group` and `.col-md-4` in the inputs, but doesn't work well (there's no margin-bottom in form-group inside dropdown-menu, you'd need to edit via CSS). Bootstrap has `.dropdown-menu` class with `min-width: 160px`. You need to overwrite to something like:

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  min-width: 200px;
}
```

[**Check the jsFiddle example.**](http://jsfiddle.net/thiagobraga/d3fLQ/)

Comment: Well, for now I I'll set up an external css for changes like this then when its finished I'll unify the both of them.

Comment: You can edit the Bootstrap LESS files and compile with your edit. The `.dropdown-menu` class is found in the `dropdowns.less` file.

Answer (score 1):

You're code seems to work fine for me.  Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q2AwW/).  I just cleaned up some of the code formatting.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Login</a> 
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <form class="navbar-form" role="form">
                    <p><input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="E-mail" /></p>
                    <p><input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Contrasenya" /></p>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Log in</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The only other resources on the page are `bootstrap.min.css`, `bootstrap.min.js`, and jQuery 1.9.1.

Comment: How you manage to do this in the fiddle? I past the same code with the same resources and my result is different